# how to keep previous ng-click initialized value as ng-init value upon refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have `ng-repeat` in which for each image the count of *like* and *dislike* buttons are changed.

However, upon refreshing the page it is giving the `ng-init` value instead of the previous incremented count of the *like* and *dislike* value.

How do I keep the incremented value even after refreshing the page?

```html
<button class="btn btn-default" id="{{$index}}" ng-click="count1=count1+1" ng-init="count1=15">Upvote <span class="badge">{{count1}}</span></button>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="{{$index}}" ng-click="count=count+1" ng-init="count=15">Downvote<span class="badge">{{count}}</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hard code the value in the `ng-init` it will always be the same. You could keep track of the like and dislike count by saving it's value in the [HTML 5 localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or use an ajax request to save and retreive the dislike data from a server with a database.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-init` will always be evoked on a page refresh. You will need a persistent back end / database of some kind, or as Nicolas stated, HTML 5 localstorage, to save your `count` values to outside the DOM.

You could also use something like [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server).

[Here is an article](https://codingthesmartway.com/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server/) on setting it up and playing with it.

[This article](https://www.genuitec.com/set-use-fake-rest-api-angular/) shows you how to connect it with Angular 4. Not the version of Angular you are using, but reading through it may help you conceptualize getting your `count` data from Angular to a persistent place.

Answer (score 0):

You can save encremented value in  Html 5 Storage , database & cookies as when ever the page is reload it will reinitialize the value.